# Android: sendBroadcast Unhandled exception in callback java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to send a broadcast from a service to my main activity. For some reason, when I call sendBroadcast I get the following warning.

```
02-26 14:55:40.615  11079-11090/com.example.sdp11.wmd W/BluetoothGatt﹕ Unhandled exception in callback
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:372)
        at com.example.sdp11.wmd.BluetoothLEService.broadcastUpdate(BluetoothLEService.java:148)
        at com.example.sdp11.wmd.BluetoothLEService.access$100(BluetoothLEService.java:28)
        at com.example.sdp11.wmd.BluetoothLEService$1.onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothLEService.java:94)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onSearchComplete(BluetoothGatt.java:301)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:215)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:412)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The method I am using to call sendBroadcast function is as follows.

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The above method is called in my Bluetooth Callback:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        //Connection established
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS
                && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Connected Successfully");
            //Discover services
            gatt.discoverServices();

        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS
                && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected");
            //Handle a disconnect event
        }

        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection state changed.  New state: " + newState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    // New services discovered
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Services discovered");
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error, onServicesDiscovered received status: " + status);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is in my onCreate method for the main activity:

```
public static BluetoothLEService mBluetoothLEService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    createLocationRequest();

    mBluetoothLEService = new BluetoothLEService();
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLEService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLEService = ((BluetoothLEService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLEService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        //mBluetoothLEService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        Log.e(TAG, "Service Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLEService = null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, finally. I am using fragments in a view pager for tabs. I get an instance of mBluetoothLEService from the main activity in the onCreate method of the fragment. The problem is that this mBluetoothLEService is still null at this point. I ended up just using MainActivity.mBluetoothLEService.broadcastUpdate() from the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Where is ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED declared? Has it been initialized? Make sure it's declared, initialized and you have access to it.

Comment: yes,  ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED is a string defined as "<mypackagename>. ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED".

Comment: I get the same error if I call sendBroadcast(null) from an activity. Are you sure that your Intent is not null when you call sendBroadcast()? The code looks like you have a reference to a non-null object but your errors say otherwise. Are there other places your calling sendBroadcast()?

Comment: Yes, I checked if the intent was null when called, and it's not. I also added a log message to get the action from the intent, and that is correct as well.

Comment: I have looked at that answer as well. I will edit my original question with the bindService call.